# one out of three bougainvillea plant does not grow

Tags: dead-branch, bougainvillea

I have three bougainvillea plants planted in 40 cm tall pots. With a mixture of universal substrate with hummus (horse, purchased) and some perlite. They are pretty much in the same corner and get watered at the same time.

- One of them is short but thick and green, full of leaves
- the second one is super tall, like 2m+
- the third one is dead. It is not dead, since I can see green if I scratch the surface. But not a single leaf or flower is there…

Can anyone tell me what can I do to help the dead one?

PS: the dead one is in the corner. But my gf decided to buy a new one and plant it in the same pot... But don't be fooled, the plant we are talking about is the leaf-less thing
PPS: It is Barcelona, April, 15-25 C. All three plants are like 1.5 years old, coming from the same shop at the same time.

[image]